# Associating xxxx_id with xxxx.id

Tags: javascript, html

I am running into a problem where when I submit a "property listing" I get this response:

```
{"owner_id":"Batman","address":"test","state":"test","sale_price":"test"}
```

The thing is "owner_id" is supposed to equal or associate with owner's id in a different table/JSON file (e.g owner_id = owner.id), not a string in this case which is why the object is not saving on the back-end.

Is anyone in vanilla JavaScript able to show me an example on how to associate owner_id and  owner.id?

Comment: Just try to submit like

{"owner":{"id":"Batman"},"address":"test","state":"test","sale_price":"test"}

Answer (score 2):

It'd be more like :

```json
{
   owner: {
      id: "Batman"
   },
   address: "test",
   state: "test",
   sale_price: "test"
}
```

You should take a look at : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Well....one of the keys in the object is actually owner_id not owner.id. owner.id is from another table that I am trying to associate with. Another way to look at this this is a primary key and a foreign key. Sorry for the lack of clarification on that part.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Not sure how you're fetching this data but it seems like you want to handle the response you're getting.

Here is a simple GET request using the fetch api:

```
fetch('http://example.com/heroes') //this is the path to your source where you're getting your response data

  .then((response) => {
    return response.json(); 
//above you return a promise containing your response data
//you can also handle your response before declaring it in a var here

  })
  .then((myJson) => { 
  //you have stored your response data as a var myJson
    console.log(myJson);

    //here you can work your response data in any way you need
    // to show an example (not that you would do this) I've provided a owner object that checks if it's property is equal to the incoming data

    var owner = {
      "id": Batman,
    }

   if ( myJson.owner_id === owner.id ) {
    //do something here
   }
  });
```

More info **[here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)**

Comment: Well....one of the keys in the object is actually owner_id, not owner.id. owner.id is from another table that I am trying to associate with. Another way to look at this this is a primary key and a foreign key. Sorry for the lack of clarification on that part.

Comment: Are you fetching this data? Do you want to store the response in a variable and then handle it?

Comment: Yes this is in my particular case. I haven't been able to find a good example of this

Comment: You can use the fetch API to handle your response. Also, if available, look into the documentation for the API you're using to get the data you provided. - I would look into tutorials for how to handle response data. The way you handle your request can be different depending on preference, and the API you're using.

Comment: Looking at your example... looks like I am going to create some variable on handling the data, assuming that I'm not just trying to log the resolved request

Comment: Correct, you can do whatever you want with it after you get the response. At that point, it is a javascript object that you can manipulate.

Comment: I should have had a better example, but I was too tired to post a bunch of code that might confuse people.

Comment: I updated my example with more comments, but yes a better example would have helped to answer your question more directly.